# Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The index 'IX_Alias_Alias' is dependent on column 'Alias'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Want to change the collation

using the below script

```
ALTER TABLE Alias ALTER COLUMN Alias nvarchar(25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS
```

Error occurs

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The index 'IX_Alias_Alias' is dependent on column 'Alias'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Alias failed because one or more objects access this column.

Actually I want to change the collation of all the table in database

Comment: DROP the index, then add it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below link to alter the collation of all the objects in a database.

[Alter Collation for all the objects in a DB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/302405/The-Easy-way-of-changing-Collation-of-all-Database)

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the index first and then modify the column.